# Difference between bound imports and delayed imports in PE header

Tags: reverse-engineering, portable-executable

could any one please explain the differences between the bound imports  and delayed imports in PE header.I have referred few books but i cannot get to understand the concept of it clearly.can anyone help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and use a Title that explains the Problem a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bound imports means that in PE-import table store fixed (bound) addresses of import functions for a specific version of DLL with those function. Bound addresses are calculated and written to import table by linker during program compilation and linking phase.

Delayed imports means that in import table instead of import functions addresses contains addresses of a special program part called "delay load helper" (sometimes is called also "thunk"), which substitutes real imported function address when the function is called for the first time. And subsequent function calls use real function address written by delay load helper.

It is the concept. Details you can find in Iczelion's PE tutorial, for example